# Actionbarsherlock. Could not find actionbarsherlock.apk!

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android, lib

Хочу в проект добавить библиотеку, вылетает эта ошибка

[2014-03-05 11:27:11 - actionbarsherlock] Could not find actionbarsherlock.apk!

[image]

[image]

Comment: а вы пробовали ставить галку `"is library"`?

Comment: @ua6xh галочка стоит.

Comment: вы уверены, что проект открыт в этом же воркспейсе, и путь у него правильный?

Comment: Я не помню, Eclipse норм с русскими путями работает или нет?
Да и  actionbarsherlock.apk! это разве библиотека, это же установочный файл приложения.